# How to login in database if we have lost password?

Tags: sql-server, logins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gain admin access to sql express 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24306/gain-admin-access-to-sql-express-2008)

Is there any idea if we lost our password to login in database using sql express management studio?
Is there any place where username and password saved on installation time of any sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's SQL Server Express 2005-2008R2 and you cannot get in, you can use this method:
http://www.netspi.com/blog/2012/08/16/sql-server-2008-local-administrator-privilege-escalation/

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to DB with local Windows authetication and change the sa password.